# Как данный код на stream может компилироваться и работать?

Tags: java

Как данный код может выполняться и компилироваться если при action.perform, метод perform даже не определен. И плюс команда типа editor в момент `m.record(editor::save);`,
а сам список macro преназначен для объектов типа action? Как такое может быть?

```
public class Macro {
    List<Actiona> macro;

    Macro(){
        macro = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void record(Actiona action){
        macro.add(action);
    }

    public void run(){
        macro.forEach(Actiona::perform);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MockEditor editor = new MockEditor();
        Macro m = new Macro();
        m.record(editor::save);
        m.record(editor::close);
        m.run();
    }
}

public class MockEditor implements Editor {

    @Override
    public void save() {
        System.out.println("Save");
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("close");
    }
}

public interface Actiona {
    public void perform();
}

public interface Editor {
    public void save();
    public void close();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Эту магию легко понять, если пойти в IDE (скажем IDEA) и попросить заменить лямду на анонимный класс:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MockEditor editor = new MockEditor();
    Macro m = new Macro();

    m.record(new Actiona() { // вместо m.record(editor::save);
        @Override
        public void perform() {
            editor.save();
        }
    });

    m.record(new Actiona() { // вместо m.record(editor::close);
        @Override 
        public void perform() {
            editor.close();
        }
    });

    m.run(); // Вызываем метод с двумя объектами Actiona
```

И неожиданно все становится простым и понятным, мы реализуем метод perform вызывая внутри методы `editor.save()` и `editor.close()`, так что поведение вполне корректное.

Очень хорошое умение, как только запутался в ламбда-функциях, заменяй их мысленно (или с помощью IDE) на анонимные классы и жить становится проще.